# Coloring of cells based on cell value using open XML in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, openxml

I have exported the data in excel using Open XML now I need to add color to the cells of few columns based on cell values.

I have taken help from the below link to do the exporting:
http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2012/03/writing-large-amounts-of-data-from.html

Can anyone help me with the coloring part.  My data is in data table.

sample image: http://tinypic.com/r/2yuwnbl/8

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code ...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;

namespace webapp1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    DataTable dtDetails = new DataTable();


    protected void Grd_QADetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var dataRowView = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
            DataRow row = dataRowView.Row;

            var Current = (row["Dosage"] as int?) ?? null;


            if (Current != null)
            {
                if (Current >= 1 && Current < 10)
                    e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = Color.Green;

                else if (Current >= 10 && Current < 20)
                    e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = Color.Yellow;

                else
                    e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        dtDetails.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        dtDetails.Columns.Add("Drug Suggested", typeof(string));
        dtDetails.Columns.Add("Patient Name", typeof(string));
        dtDetails.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
        dtDetails.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
        dtDetails.Columns.Add("Payment Mode", typeof(string));
        dtDetails.Columns.Add("Appointment Status", typeof(string));
        dtDetails.Columns.Add("Location", typeof(string));

        dtDetails.Rows.Add(1, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
        dtDetails.Rows.Add(2, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
        dtDetails.Rows.Add(3, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
        dtDetails.Rows.Add(4, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
        dtDetails.Rows.Add(5, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");

        dtDetails.Rows.Add(6, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
        dtDetails.Rows.Add(7, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
        dtDetails.Rows.Add(8, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
        dtDetails.Rows.Add(9, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
        dtDetails.Rows.Add(10, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");

        dtDetails.Rows.Add(11, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
        dtDetails.Rows.Add(12, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
        dtDetails.Rows.Add(13, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
        dtDetails.Rows.Add(14, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");
        dtDetails.Rows.Add(15, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now, "Casuality", "Cash", "Pending", "Kolkatta");



        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            grdDetails.DataSource = dtDetails;
            grdDetails.DataBind();
        }

    }

    protected void ExportToGrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ExportToGrid(dtDetails);
    }

    private void ExportToGrid(DataTable dt)
    {

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string filename = "Test" + ".xls";

            using (System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
            {
                System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
                GridView dgGrid = new GridView();
                dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
                dgGrid.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(Grd_QADetails_RowDataBound);
                dgGrid.DataBind();

                //Get the HTML for the control.
                dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
                //Write the HTML back to the browser.

                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
                this.EnableViewState = false;

                Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">" + Environment.NewLine);
                Response.Write(tw.ToString());

                Response.Write("</body>");
                Response.Write("</html>");

                Response.End();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="webapp1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdDetails" OnRowDataBound="Grd_QADetails_RowDataBound">

    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button  runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="ExportToGrid"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I am using WPF so from observable collection I took data in data table. There is no Gridview is involved in any case.I want it through Open XML library.Pls guide